# math function passed through a list

Tags: python

I have to create individual scores from the keyboard and store them in a list. Then call each of the three functions,passing the list,to compute the average, highest, and lowest score. ##note create 3 functions (ave,high,low),and pass the list to each

What am I doing wrong??

I'm a mess right now with this sorry for all the extra stuff!

```
def getScores():
    """This function asks the user for list of scores
    """
    validNums=("0123456789")
    lstScores=[ ]
    strNum="0"
    while len(strNum) > 0:
         strNum=raw_input("Enter a number or press ENTER when done: ")
        if len(strNum) > 0:
            for digit in strNum:
                if digit in validNums:
                    lstScores.append(int(strNum))
                else:
                    print "invalid data entered!"

    return lstScores

def DataSort(sortedScores=[ ]):
    sortedScores.sort()
    return sortedScores

def Average(avgScores=[]):
    sum(lstScores) / len(lstScores)
    for avg in avgScores:
        print avgScores

    return avgScores


##def DataPrint(scoresToPrint=[ ]):
##    for score in scoresToPrint:
##        print score ####list sort

 ###MAINLINE
 lstScores=getScores()
 ##sortedScores=DataSort(sortedScores=lstScores)
 avgScores=Average()
 ##DataPrint(scoresToPrint=sortedScores)
print
print lstScores
print
print avgScores
##print sortedScores
##for num in lstScores:
##    print num

##for avg in avgScores:
    ##print avg
```

Comment: What's going wrong for you? Not getting the right output? Not getting any output? etc...

Comment: So I can get the list to go through but when I try to get the average it says none.

Comment: or just gives me [] its not giving me any output for the average

Comment: What is `lstScores`? It's not passed to `Average`. Is it a global? Also, as someone else mentioned in a deleted answer, you do a bunch of stuff with `lstScores` but you don't store the result anywhere. In general, your `Average` function is strange. And finally, is this homework? If so, tag it as homework.

Comment: Independent of the issues involving how and when to pass arguments to functions, the logic of getScores() looks off to me.  It will currently append an entered number (like `123`) once for every digit, which I don't think is what's intended.

Comment: Don't use a list as a default function argument: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you pass a default value for `avgScores` in the function `Average`, but this will work for finding the average:

```
def Average(lstScores):
    return float(sum(lstScores)) / len(lstScores) if lstScores else 0.0
```

Call it like this:

```
Average(lstScores)
```

Also, I'm assuming scores are in the range 0-9, if a score is greater than 9 the validation logic in `getScores()` will fail.

Comment: @DSM thanks, it's not safe to assume that everybody uses Python 3 :)

Comment: Especially not with print statements. :^)

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems.

1. You're adding numbers multiple times to your list.
2. You're computing the average of an empty list! You need to pass `lstScores` to the function `Average()`. I've fixed the code for you, but now it'll throw a `ValueError` if you write a non-integer number. I leave it to you to figure out the exception handling.
3. Your `Average()` function didn't actually compute the average...

   ```
   def getScores():
       """This function asks the user for list of scores
       """
       validNums=("0123456789")
       lstScores=[ ]
       strNum="0"
       while len(strNum) > 0:
           strNum=raw_input("Enter a number or press ENTER when done: ")
           if len(strNum) > 0:
               lstScores.append(int(strNum))

       return lstScores

   def DataSort(sortedScores=[ ]):
       sortedScores.sort()
       return sortedScores

   def Average(avgScores=[]):
       avg = sum(lstScores) / float(len(lstScores))
       return avg 

   lstScores=getScores()

   avgScores=Average(lstScores)

   print lstScores
   print "Average of scores: " + str(avgScores)
   ```